# How to determine uncovered fixed units using RadioMobile

Tags: software-recommendations

I've been tasked with determining if certain houses in a specific area won't be covered by a proposed radio network. The houses and stations are fixed but I'm using RadioMobile which doesn't seem to have a batch RadioLink feature (gets the direct line connection with the final signal strength at the end point). My current solution is to generate a bunch of very high resolution coverage maps and then import the sig/txt coverage into QGIS but to get the right resolution takes a huge amount of time to process.

The batch options in RadioMobile are for cartesian maps only but I only need the signal strength at +-500 unique coordinates/points which means it would be cumbersome to do it manually, one by one.

Are there any faster yet still reasonably accurate ways of accomplishing this?